# Passing arguments with variables in PowerShell to native application

Tags: powershell, svn

Here is a part from my deployment automation script:

```
$SVNEXE = "$env:ProgramFiles\TortoiseSVN\bin\svn.exe"
foreach ($element in $commandstoken) {
#$exportfile = [System.Web.HttpUtility]::UrlPathDecode($StreamServe5RepoURI + $commandstoken[$a])
$exportfile = ($StreamServe5RepoURI + $commandstoken[$a])
$SVNRevision = $commandstoken[$a+1]
[string]$SVNCommand = "export -r $SVNRevision --force"
Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red $SVNCommand
Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red $SVNCommand $exportfile
&"$SVNEXE" $SVNCommand $exportfile "C:\Temp\__foo\export"
$a = $a+2
}
```

I want to pass the svn.exe the `$SVNCommand` variable but the svn.exe throws an error: `svn.exe : Unknown subcommand: 'export -r 2384 --force'`
As far as I can see the variable expansion is working so I can not understand why the `svn.exe` throws this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I got it to work is to hold every parameter in a separate variable:

```
$arg1 = 'export', '-r'
$arg2 = $SVNRevision
$arg3 = '--force'
$arg4 = $exportfile
$arg5 = 'C:\Temp\__foo\export\'
&"$SVNEXE" $arg1 $arg2 $arg3 $arg4 $arg5
```

This seems actually bug [Executing commands which require quotes and variables is practically impossible](https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/376207/executing-commands-which-require-quotes-and-variables-is-practically-impossible)

Comment: Thanks for this, it took way too long to figure out how to do such a simple thing, batch scripts are much easier for something like this.

Comment: Wow, SVN wants the first argument to be an array?   That's nuts.

Answer (score 7):

The error `Unknown subcommand: 'export -r 2384 --force'` suggests that call operator treats  `'export -r 2384 --force''export -r 2384 --force'` this like a single argument ([from technet on the & call operator](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7703.powershell-running-executables.aspx)):

> Things can get tricky when an external command has a lot of parameters
>   or there are spaces in the arguments or paths! With spaces you have to
>   nest Quotation marks and the result it is not always clear!

In your case, you could do something like like suggested on that page:

```
 $SVNcommand = @('export', '-r', $SVNRevieion, "--force", $exportfile, "C:\Temp\__foo\export")
```

And invoke with all arguments like this:

```
&"$SVNEXE" $SVNCommand
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I just tried as suggest but the command still fails. If print out the $SVNCommand with Write-Host everything looks good. I can even copy and paste the command line to the CMD where everything works as expected.

Comment: Yes, that has to do with the way write-host prints out arrays. To the call operator & what you pass in your powershell script maps to command arguments, so the issue you face relates to how the svn.exe interprets the arguments. What error do you get after trying the solution I suggested?

Comment: Thx for the fast reply.

Here is the error:

export -r 2384 --force https://example.com/svn/repository/Dir1/SubDir/SubDir/SubDir/file.txt C:\Temp\__foo\export
svn.exe : Unknown subcommand: 'export -r 2384 --force https://example.com/svn/repository/Dir1/SubDir/SubDir/SubDir/file.txt 
C:\Temp\__foo\export'
In C:\Temp\__foo\SVN Export.ps1:16 Zeichen:1
+ &"$SVNEXE" $SVNCommand
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Unknown subcomm...p\__foo\export':String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
 
Type 'svn help' for usage.

Comment: Try building your command like this `& "$SVNexe" @("export", "-r")` and see where the errors no longer makes sense for what your're trying to do!

Comment: Is quoting a variable name necessary?  wouldn't the invoke use the value from the variable exactly the same as if it was not quoted?